# scraping a subscribed website for video links

Tags: python, web-scraping, add-on, kodi

I use Kodi with add-ons such as Exodus which allow me to load episodes of my favourite TV programs etc, and I also have a subscription to horse and country to watch equine based shows but there is not a horse and country add-on to allow me to watch these on Kodi.

Is it possible for me to be able to code an add-on for Kodi (presumably in Python?) that would obtain all of the possible video links from www.horseandcountry.tv (catch up and on demand) using my log-in details and list these for me to watch.

I have a fair bit of experience coding (mostly Java, and a little Python), but have never written a Kodi add-on or done anything that scrapes video links from websites etc. I'm a first year computer science student so have a bit of understanding but not much experience!

First off, is what I am looking to do realistic and possible? and secondly, if so, would someone be able to give a very brief overview of how I would go about it and the necessary principles involved?

Comment: Sorry, while interesting, your Q is too broad for S.O. We're here to help you fix your scrapper code, but not to spec and design it ;-). Aren't the Kodi developer forums? Certainly you'll tap into more experience there AND this sort of Q would (presumably) be on-topic. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I was certainly not expecting anyone to help me design anything...just provide a starting point for my research and reading! Though you are right...the kodi forums would be far more appropriate, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your going to write a python addon, in this case probably a plugin is fitted best.
Have a look at https://github.com/Razzeee/generator-kodi for a good quickstart/boilerplate. (Let me know if you spot something wrong)

You might also want to use beautifulsoup to grab the links via python.